# Project Euler problem 67: find maximum cost path in 100-row triangle

Tags: data-structures, puzzle

In [Project Euler's problem 67](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=67) there is a triangle given and it contains 100 rows. For e.g.

```
        5
      9  6
    4   6  8
  0   7  1   5

I.e. 5 + 9 + 6 + 7 = 27.
```

Now I have to find the maximum total from top to bottom in given 100 rows triangle.

I was thinking about which data structure should I use so that problem will get solved efficiently.

Comment: Store each row as a vector and take the max.

Comment: What data structure were you thinking about? @PengOne that won't work, based on the provided solution - it looks like the numbers need to be "adjacent."

Comment: @PengOne: I assume a value in a row must be adjacent to the value picked in the previous one. It is not just one of the values (otherwise it would be `8` in the third row).

Comment: @Matt Ball - Well, he didn't specific that. Good observation though.

Comment: @PengOne: Well, the maximum value in the third row is `8` but he chose `6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to store this as a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). The nodes are the entries of your triangular array, and there is an arrow from `i` to `j` iff `j` is one row lower and immediately left or right of `i`.

Now you want to find the [maximum weight directed path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) (sum of the vertex weights) in this graph. In general, this problem is NP-complete, however, as templatetypedef points out, there are efficient algorithms for DAGs; [here's one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Weighted_directed_acyclic_graphs):

```
algorithm dag-longest-path is
    input: 
         Directed acyclic graph G
    output: 
         Length of the longest path

    length_to = array with |V(G)| elements of type int with default value 0

    for each vertex v in topOrder(G) do
        for each edge (v, w) in E(G) do
            if length_to[w] <= length_to[v] + weight(G,(v,w)) then
                length_to[w] = length_to[v] + weight(G, (v,w))

    return max(length_to[v] for v in V(G))
```

To make this work, you will need to weight the `length` of the path to be the size of the target node (since all paths include the source, this is fine).

Comment: It won't actually be a tree, as there can be two arrows coming from above to the same node.  But it's a directed acyclic graph, and this is a sensible data structure. for the problem.

Comment: @Don... I had logged off for the day, but that realization bugged me enough to log back on and fix it.

Comment: This general problem is NP-hard, but because the graph is a DAG the maximum-weight path can be computed in linear time using dynamic programming.

Comment: You could use a* to find the desired path. Using `node.val + (node.height()-1) * 99;` as heuristic. If you're going down the graph hole.

Answer (score 1):

Which language are you using?

A muti-dimensional array is probably the best way to store the values, then depending on the language, there are options for how you store pointers or references to where in the arrays you are.

Answer (score 1):

To build off of @Matt Wilson's answer, using a two-dimensional array to hold the numbers would be a fairly simple solution.  In your case, you would encode the triangle

```
      5
    9  6
  4   6  8
0   7  1   5
```

as the array

```
[5][ ][ ][ ]
[9][6][ ][ ]
[4][6][8][ ]
[0][7][1][5]
```

From here, a node at position (i, j) has children at (i + 1, j) and (i + 1, j + 1) and parents at position (i - 1, j) and (i - 1, j - 1), assuming those indices are valid.

The advantage of this approach is that if your triangle has height N, the space required for this approach is N<sup>2</sup>, which is just less than twice the N(N + 1) / 2 space required to actually store the elements.  A linked structure like an explicit graph would certainly use more memory than that.

Comment: Wasteful on memory.  A tree would be better.  A binary tree array would be perfect.

Comment: @duffymo- Can you elaborate on how the tree is more memory efficient?  The overhead per element here is one extra integer per integer used.  A binary tree would need two pointers/indices per integer used, which is less efficient.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a Project Euler problem.

It can't be represented with a binary tree. Any kind of graph is overkill as well, though the problem can be solved with a longest path algorithm in directed acyclic graphs. Edit: Nevermind that, it is only useful if the edges are weighted, not the nodes.

A two dimensional vector (e.g. `vector<vector<int> >`) is more than enough to represent such triangles, and there is a straightforward solution using such representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() { 
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > lines;
    lines.resize(100);
    std::ifstream input("triangle.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            std::string number_string;
            input >> number_string;
            std::istringstream temp(number_string);
            int value = 0;
            temp >> value;
            lines[i].push_back(value);
        }
    } 
    std::vector<int> path1;
    path1.resize(100);
    std::vector<int> path2;
    path2.resize(100);

    for (int i = 0;i < 100;i++) 
        path1[i] = lines[99][i];

    for (int i = 98; i >= 0;i--) {  
        for(int j = 0;j < i+1;j++) {
            if(path1[j] > path1[j + 1]){
                path2[j] = path1[j] + lines[i][j];
            } else{
                path2[j] = path1[j + 1] + lines[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0;i < 100;i++) 
            path1[i] = path2[i];
    }
    std::cout << path1[0] << std::endl;
}
```