# Adding a triangle up from the bottom rows

Tags: python, loops

I'm taking some guidance from this question ([Max path triangle (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303553/max-path-triangle-python)) but I stumbled upon it after I already started to write out what I thought.

I want to find the maximum of numbers within a triangle, leading from the bottom to the top. So once the loops reach the end the final position of the triangle will be the largest addition of the numbers from the rows below.

For instance...if this was the triangle:

```
   2
  3 7
 8 2 10
2 6 9 4
```

It adds row n with row n-1 to mind the maximum values, so if my code ran the triangle would look like this after one iteration.

```
    2
   3 7
 14 11 19
```

However the code I've written seems to not replace the elements in the list above.

```
for i in range(len(a)-1, 0, 1):
  for j in range(0, len(a[i])-1, 1):
    '''
    i = Row position
    j = Column position
    '''

    a[i-1][j] = max(a[i][j] + a[i-1][j], a[i][j+1] + a[i-1][j])
print a
```

I know it works, because when I put in numbers to check it spits out the correct answer. From the triangle I provided, the first numbers checked would be 2+8 and 6+8, making 14 the correct answer.

So what is wrong with my code?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm confused -- first you say "I know it works", but then you say "What is wrong with my code?"  Can you be more clear about what the problem that you're seeing is exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `for` statement, you need to change the delta to -1. You can't go from len(a)-1 to 0 with positive numbers

```
for i in range(len(a)-1, 0, -1):
  for j in range(0, len(a[i])-1, 1):
    '''
    i = Row position
    j = Column position
    '''

    a[i-1][j] = max(a[i][j] + a[i-1][j], a[i][j+1] + a[i-1][j])
print a
```

Comment: That makes sense. I thought python would pick up on the direction of the range.